# After hovering over a button for longer than 2 seconds, I have to rehover over that button in order to be able to click on it again

Tags: css, html, animation, hover

I introduced a hover animation over a button. The hover animation works perfectly fine, but it has the side-effect that you can no longer click on the button once the animation ends. I would like to change this but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
    .chooseFileBtn, .submitFileBtn{ /* ignore the '.submiteFileBtn' here */
    margin-top:180%;
    padding-left: 30%;
    padding-right:30%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #E55300;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    /*transition: all 0.5s; */
}

.chooseFileBtn:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:34.1%;
    left:41.1%;
    height:5.6%;
    width:0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

.chooseFileBtn:hover:before {
    width:8.72%;
}
```

The chooseFileBtn is just a standard button, it shouldn't be relevant for the solution to my issue, but if you would like me to share it with you then feel free to ask. Also, this is written in a seperate .css file. This .css file is linked to the main .html file.

Comment: I cant seem to see any animation by using your code.. Can you create a fiddle for your animation that is causing the issue ?

Comment: [This](http://www.developerdrive.com/2015/01/8-simple-css-hover-effects/) is the link to the website that I used to construct the animation. The animation that I used is the first one on the website: Horizontal Immersion.

Comment: I am able to click my button just fine even after the animation ends. What issue are you facing? Is your click is not firing or something like that ? please elaborate if you can

Comment: If I hover over the button I can initially click it, but as soon as the animation is finished, meaning that the button is filled from left to right, my click doesn't do anything anymore. After the animation, the button no longer works. I have to remove my cursor from the button, let it 'reset' to it's original color, and then I can click on it again.

Comment: Maybe it is the code for chooseFileBtn that is causing the trouble? Just in case I will paste the code for the button here: 

    <div class="chooseFileBtn">
              <a href="#"  id="uploadLink" onClick="chooseUpload();"> 
   <h1 align="center" id="chooseFileBtnText">Upload file</h1></a>
              </div>

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to wrap your anchor in a div!! 
That is why your anchor is not working after animation because it covers your anchor.

```
<a class="chooseFileBtn" href="#" id="uploadLink" onClick="chooseUpload();">
    <h1 align="center" id="chooseFileBtnText">Upload file</h1>
</a>
```

CSS

```
  .chooseFileBtn, .submitFileBtn{ /* ignore the '.submiteFileBtn' here */
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #E55300;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    /*transition: all 0.5s; */
}

.chooseFileBtn:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:50%;
    width:0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

.chooseFileBtn:hover:before {
    width:100%;
}
```

See my fidde  https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/47362/

Comment: Changing this did indeed fix my issue, but it led to my button being being messed up. Is there a way to avoid this or will I simply have to rewrite the code that defined the button's margin's etc?

Comment: You dont need to copy paste my exact css. All I did to css was to make it work for my fiddle. You just need to add the chooseFileBtn class directly to the anchor. and adjust rest of your css accordingly. I have changed the margins/paddings etc as they were irrelevant for my fiddle to work properly.

Comment: I simply removed the <div class='chooseFileBtn'></div> and added class="chooseFileBtn" to the anchor but this still led to issues regarding the button. Is there a better way to do this or am I simply making a mistake?

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea why you have added so many styles for such a simple button! but then again i dont know your website struture so i cant comment on that. The least i can say is try with my css also. and remove your own styles. If that doesnt work again then I m afraid you may have to rework

Comment: Okay, I'm afraid I'll have to rework the code then. Regardless, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Good luck with that :) and let me know if it works in the end.